# How to convert a Fetch API response to RxJS Observable?

Tags: rxjs, es6-promise, fetch-api

How can I convert whatever [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) returns to [RxJS Observable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/promises.md)? Does [RxJS.fromPromise](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md) help?

Comment: You might want to consider using Angular's HTTP service if you are using Angular or RxJS's [`AjaxObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.4.1/src/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts#L101-L126) if you are not. They have the advantage of being cancellable; promises cannot be cancelled.

Comment: It is an Angular app that uses an Observable, but this app works in a web worker. The Angular HTTP is not compatible with web worker. I had to hack it to work. Doesn't it still use ```XMLHttpRequest``` compred to FetchAPI which has better performance than ```XMLHttpRequest```?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

check out this [article](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise)

```
var result = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://myserver.com/'));
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.error(e));
```

Answer (score 45):

As fetch call returns yet another promise containing the response object, I'd go with creating your own observable:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const data$ = Observable.create(observer => {
  fetch('http://server.com')
    .then(response => response.json()) // or text() or blob() etc.
    .then(data => {
      observer.next(data);
      observer.complete();
    })
    .catch(err => observer.error(err));
});

data$.subscribe(data => /*do something with data*/);
```

Comment: Don't really get why this was downvoted. I think it's actually a more robust solution that the accepted answer. `Observable.fromPromise(fetch(..))` will fire the request right away, while the above will effectively start it after `.subscribe()`.

Comment: I don't see any reason to import map operator here.

Comment: Observable.create() is deprecated.
Instead, use:`const data$ = new Observable(observer => {...})`

Comment: @Dacomis I don't see anything about deprecation in the docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Observable#create

Comment: @wawka this deprecation error appeared in my VSCode due to TSLint.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using rxjs@6.

The operator that accepts observables(like `flatMap`, `switchMap`, etc...) can also accept promise.
it's very simple as follows.

```
somethingObservable.pipe(
    flatMap(() => fetch('http://some.api.com/post/1')),
    subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    }),
)
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using rxjs 6.5.3. I am using below example to convert Fetch API response to RxJS Observable.

```
const { from } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap } = rxjs.operators


const observable = from(fetch('data/user.json')).pipe(
    switchMap(response => response.json())
)

observable.subscribe(function(result){
    console.log('result', result);
});
```

You can also use [[fromFetch](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/fetch/fromFetch)](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/fetch/fromFetch) of rxjs. But fetch API are still experimental.

Answer (score 4):

Using rxjs   6.4  you can use the  **from**  operator

See this link: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html

Example is in TS:

```
public getModelDetails(): Observable<YourType> {

const apiCall = fetch(`yourURL/modelDetails`)
                   .then(response => response.json())
                   .then(responseJson => {
                          return responseJson as YourType
                    })
return from(apiCall)
```

}

Comment: This is also the recommended way for Angular: https://angular.io/guide/rx-library

Answer (score 2):

There exist libary [rxjs-fetch](https://github.com/tangledfruit/rxjs-fetch), but I would suggest not to use it, and write instead:

```
const getData = (url, params) => {
    return fetch(url, params).then(r => {
        return r.ok ? r.text() : Promise.reject(`${r.statusText} ${r.status}`)
    })
}

const getDataObserver = (url, params) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getData())
```

(in NodeJS you will require [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch))

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I used [fromFetch](https://rxjs.dev/api/fetch/fromFetch):

```
import { fromFetch } from 'rxjs/fetch';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const $observable = <T>(url: string, body: T) => fromFetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    selector: (response) => response.json(),
}).pipe(tap(data => console.log('fetch data:', data)));

$observable('https://your-url.com', { somePayload: '' }).subscribe({
    next: result => console.log(result),
    complete: () => console.log('done')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With observables it's recommended to make a fetch cancelable:

```
function fetch$(url:string, options:RequestInit) {
  return new Observable<Response>(subscriber => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    options.signal = controller.signal;
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => {
      subscriber.next(res);
      subscriber.complete();
    })
    .catch(er => subscriber.error(er));
    return () => { // <- return the observable teardown function
      controller.abort();
    }
  })
}
```

See https://davidwalsh.name/cancel-fetch