# How do I convert httpclient to fetch api using Angular and use pipe over it?

Tags: angular, rxjs, pipe, httpclient, fetch-api

As part of a project, I need to rewrite part of an angular code working using httpclient with fetch api. Herein is the original code:

```
        return this.httpClient.get(targetUrl, { headers: { 'responseType': 'json' }, params: params }).pipe(
            map((namedSelection) => {
                this.namedSelections.set(componentId.toString() + '.' + name, namedSelection);
            })
        )
```

I changed it to this:

```
const request = from(fetch(targetUrl, { headers: { 'responseType': 'json' }, method: 'GET' }).then(request => request.json()));

        return request.pipe(
            map((namedSelection) => {
                this.namedSelections.set(componentId.toString() + '.' + name, namedSelection);
            })
        )
```

But it's not working. Maybe I structured it incorrectly. I am a beginner in coding so would like to know what's the right way to write this? I apologise in advance if the questions seems trivial.

Comment: The problem is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057685/2976617 Pay attention to the two `thens`. As the example is a bit old now, `create` is deprecated so create an Observable like [that](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with RxJS from method, and I prefer create cold observable manually from the fetch method, something like this should works

```js
const request = new Observable(obs => {
    fetch(targetUrl, { headers: { 'responseType': 'json' }, method: 'GET'})
   .then(result => {
      obs.next(result.json);
      obs.complete();
    })
   .catch(error => {
      obs.error(error);
      obs.complete();
    })

});


return request.pipe(
     map((namedSelection) => {
        this.namedSelections.set(componentId.toString() + '.' + name, namedSelection);
     })
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help me out. But it seems to be having the same trouble as before. The return value is undefined.