# FetchApi and rxjs: I don't see any data in the reponse

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, mergeMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Examples: kumar
const url = 'https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?name=';

// elem ref
const searchBox = document.getElementById('search');

// streams
const keyup$ = fromEvent(searchBox, 'keyup');

keyup$
  .pipe(
    map((i: any) => i.currentTarget.value),
    debounceTime(500),
    mergeMap((v) => fetch(url + v)),
    tap((result) => {
      console.log('JSON: ', result.json());
    })
  )
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

You can copy and paste it into https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-adheqt?devtoolsheight=50&file=index.ts

But I don't see the JSON result. Please help, I don't understand why I don't see any data.

PS: I don't want to use fromFetch. It's just for learning purposes and I would like to use the fetch api.
[image]

Comment: It's because result.json() also returns a promise..

`mergeMap(v => fetch(url+v).then(result => result.json()))`

Would result in the JSON response from the fetch being passed into the observable as a single item, if you then want that array to be different items in the observable you can do another mergeMap.

Comment: Exactly @pont, please have a look how to convert `fetch` to an observable: [fetch to observable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47057685/2976617)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json()` returns a promise so you still need to resolve that promise/observable :

```
keyup$
  .pipe(
    map((i: any) => i.currentTarget.value),
    mergeMap((e) => fetch(`https://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users?name=${e}`)),
    mergeMap(response => response.json()), // json() resolved using mergeMap
    debounceTime(500)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```